# How to cancel 'slow' chain of promises

Tags: node.js, express, promise

As far as I can tell this is not possible, so perhaps I need another solution to this problem. (If you then know what that it, do let me know).

So. I have an express app. Which handles incoming requests, does something with it and returns a response. Some requests however take too much time. So, I'm using `connect-timeout` to return a response to the user (which just says that a timeout has occurred to the client).

At that point there is no use to continue handling that request, but there's no way to really do that. Any promises that have been started for the request for async tasks are continuing to do their work. But the result no longer applies since that will not be send to the client.

Is it possible to easily stop a promise and all it's 'child' tasks? I'm kind of looking for something like this:

```
Promise.race([
    Promise.delay(30000).then(() => return Promise.reject("TOO LONG")),
    Promise.expensive_tasks_with_sub_promises()
])
.then(() => console.log("all done"))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

The all done section here won't be called if the expensive task is still pending after 30 seconds. But the expensive task is still continuing. I would like that one to stop at that point.

I can in the expensive task continuously keep track of the time, but then I'd have to do that in every of it's children too (eg if time exceeded then skip or something). And that's kind of cumbersome.

Comment: No, it's not easy, but it's possible. You will need to check after each of the "sub promises" whether your task has been cancelled, and abort.

Comment: how to for "timeouts"  :: https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/  see implement timeouts in link